# Keep Windows Application Running without a Form

Tags: .net, winforms

I have created an Windows application without showing a window form. I need to keep my application running . Now after executing all the codes application become stopped.
I try a way like below.

```
public void RunForm()
{
    var frm=new Form();
    Application.Run(frm);

}
```

the application is not stopped but showing form. How can i keep running my application without showing the form?

Comment: This may help .. http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/creating-tray-applications-in-.net-a-practical-guide/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call Application.Run() and don't pass anything.  It belongs in your Main() method.

This keeps your main thread active and responsive to Windows notifications.  Of course, there are not a lot of them since you don't have a user interface anymore.  Timers will work.  A NotifyIcon will work.  A hot key registered by pinvoking RegisterHotKey() will work.  A low-level windows hook will work.

And SystemEvents will work.  Which is important, you'll need to subscribe its SessionEnding event to know when the user is logging off or shutting down Windows, you'll need to terminate your app.  Which you do by calling Application.ExitThread().

Answer (score 1):

You could either add a Notification Icon so the application/form can be closed through a menu item or you can create a service instead of the application.

It depends on what the application should do when not visible and whether or not it needs the features of a service (running when there is no current logged in user, running on a different account)

You could even combine these two: install the service and have the forms application connect to it (WCF?) when it is started. This way the user can close the forms application while the service keeps on running.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Application.Run()` overload that takes an instance of `ApplicationContext`. The `ApplicationContext` has to explicitly call `Application.Exit()` to end execution.

```
public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnabledVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        ApplicationContext context = new MyContext();
        Application.Run(context);
    }
}

public class MyContext : ApplicationContext
{
    //    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to hide the form? I'm having trouble seeing the purpose of this (having a GUI application without a GUI), and you should probably just build a Windows Service instead. Anyway, in your form load event you can hide the form by calling `this.Hide()`.

Comment: my application is run in two mode. if the mode is windowsform(taken from the config) showing a window form else some code executes and listening for the events. So my application keeps always running

Comment: An idea might be to put your application logic in a separate UI-agnostic assembly to not being dependent on the Windows Forms functionality.